# 94' Dodge Spirit 3.0l v6 Throttle position sensor over 4.96V

Tags: engine, cel, dodge

I pulled up the codes from my 94 spirit that's been running sluggish and unresponsive lately. I got a 24* Throttle position sensor over 4.96V. I put a new TPS in and I'm still getting this code. Do I have to unplug the battery and let my computer reset? I keep seeing videos saying you can adjust your TPS but I'm not sure how they do it by moving it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you made sure to clear the codes and it came back, then you probably have high resistance or a broken wire. Most sensors on a car use voltage on sensor wire at 5V, and then ground is applied by what ever sensing mechanism and brings the voltage down... So if the sensor wire is broken or the return wire (aka ground) , the voltage can't be dropped and sticks high.

Keep in mind high Resistance could be an actual break in the wire, corrosion, or connector terminals spread open. Need to check it all.